# laptop-mode-tool not working in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, laptop-mode

I've installed `laptop-mode-tools` and optional dependencies on Arch Linux.
Then I've enabled `laptop-mode.service` and rebooted the system.

If I check if the service is actually working according to [this](http://samwel.tk/laptop_mode/faq) (Para 3. Is Laptop Mode Enabled?) I get the following:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode
0
```

The file `/var/run/laptop-mode-enabled` is not found. Finally `systemctl` tells me:

```
laptop-mode.service         loaded active exited    Laptop Mode Tools
```

All the above "symptoms" tell me that the `laptop-mode` service is not actually working.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
I have noticed that `$ cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode` gives `0` even after doing thinks like in my answer below if I boot up on battery. Then if I connect the ac adapter for a few seconds and then disconnect it, `$ cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode` will give `2`. In any case now my battery seems to last much longer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
I've switched to tlp (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TLP) which seems to work much better (at least in my experience) and works out of the box.

**Old answer:**

I think I found the solution: I have installed the following packages via yaourt:

```
$ pacman -S acpid bluez-utils wireless_tools cpupower
```

and then enabled the relevant services

```
$ systemctl enable acpid.service
$ systemctl enable cpupower.service
$ systemctl enable fancontrol
$ sensors-detect
$ systemctl enable lm_sensors.service
```

finally I have disabled/re-enabled `laptop-mode.service` (not sure it is actually needed):

```
$ systemctl disable laptop-mode.service
$ systemctl enable laptop-mode.service
```

and rebooted the system.

Now:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode
2
```

that according to official documentation should confirm that service is actually running.

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that `$ cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode` gives `0` if I boot up on battery with charge below 90%. Then if I connect the ac adapter for a few seconds and then disconnect it (or manually restart laptop-mode.service), `$ cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode` will give `2`. In any case now my battery seems to last much longer.

Comment: Note that all of these packages are in the official repositories; using `yaourt` is not required.